# Trying to remove objects of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a copy of Pac-Man with Python and  Pygame, but I'm having a problem when trying to delete the dots a pills, I'm not sure of how to do it I tried to use "del" and didn't work, I also tried adding the dots to a list and then make a for loop that iterates in every dot and remove it if the player collide with one of them, but it makes the game to laggy, how can I remove the pills from the screen?

````
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()


#Variables del juego
windowWidth = 504
windowHeight = 648
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight), 0, 32)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30


pygame.display.set_caption('Pac-Man')


#Colores
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
cyan = (0, 255, 255)
navyBlue = (0, 0, 53)
pink = (255, 192, 203)


#Tamaño del bloque

blockSize = 24
dotSize = 4
pillSize = 8

#Datos del jugador
playerSize = 24
player = pygame.Rect(240, 480, playerSize, playerSize)
speed = 5


#Variables de movimiento
moveLeft = moveRight = moveDown = moveUp = False


#Laberinto
maze = [
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "x.........x.........x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x-xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx-x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x...................x",
    "x.xxx.x.xxxxx.x.xxx.x",
    "x.xxx.x.xxxxx.x.xxx.x",
    "x.....x...x...x.....x",
    "xxxxx.xxxoxoxxx.xxxxx",
    "oooox.xooooooox.xoooo",
    "oooox.xoxxoxxox.xoooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxoooxox.xxxxx",
    "ooooo.ooxoooxoo.ooooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxxxxxox.xxxxx",
    "oooox.xooooooox.xoooo",
    "oooox.xoxxxxxox.xoooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxxxxxox.xxxxx",
    "x.........x.........x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x-..x.....o.....x..-x",
    "xxx.x.x.xxxxx.x.x.xxx",
    "xxx.x.x.xxxxx.x.x.xxx",
    "x.....x...x...x.....x",
    "x.xxxxxxx.x.xxxxxxx.x",
    "x...................x",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

]
def createMaze():
    pointX = 0
    pointY = 0
    
    for i in maze:
        for j in i:
            if j == "x":
                block = pygame.Rect(pointX, pointY, blockSize, blockSize)
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, navyBlue, block)
                if block.colliderect(player):
                    if player.bottom - block.top <  10:
                        player.y = block.top - playerSize
                    if block.bottom - player.top < 10:             
                        player.y = block.bottom
                    if block.right - player.left < 10:
                        player.x = block.right
                    if  player.right - block.left < 10:
                        player.x = block.left - playerSize
            if j == ".":
                dot = pygame.Rect(pointX + (blockSize / 2) - (dotSize / 2), pointY + (blockSize / 2) - (dotSize / 2), dotSize, dotSize)
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, dot)
            if j == "-":
                pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, white, (pointX + pillSize + (pillSize / 2), pointY + pillSize + (pillSize / 2)), pillSize)
            if j == "o":
                pass
            pointX += blockSize
        pointX = 0
        pointY += blockSize

#Función para cerrar juego
def close():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


#Ciclo principal del juego
while True:
    #Buscar evento QUIT
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            close()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                moveUp = True
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_s:                
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_a:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = True
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_d:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True



    #Mover jugador
    if moveLeft:
        player.move_ip(-1 * speed, 0)
    if moveRight:
        player.move_ip(speed, 0)
    if moveUp:
        player.move_ip(0, -1 * speed)
    if moveDown:
        player.move_ip(0, speed)


    #Portal
    if player.left > windowWidth:
        player.x = 0 - playerSize
    if player.right < 0:
        player.x = windowWidth

    windowSurface.fill(black)
    
    createMaze()
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, yellow, player)
    

    pygame.display.update()

    mainClock.tick(FPS)```
````

Answer (score -1):

I changed the "." with and "o" (that represents a emty space) by creating a new string

```
if dot.colliderect(player):
    maze[y] = maze[y][:x] + "o" + maze[y][x + 1:]
```